# Maven connection issue

Tags: java, linux, maven, connection

When I try to do "mvn clean install" in my project folder, I got a error like this:

> org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector
>   tryConnect INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException)
>   caught when connecting to the target host: No route to host

My settings.xml file is ok.
And my configuration:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 10:44:56+0200)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_33, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_33/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.24-24-server", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Please help us, boring lot :)

Comment: How do you know that `settings.xml` is OK?

Comment: do you use a proxy to access internet? If this is the case, is this properly configured in the settings.xml ?

Comment: @Tichodroma because in another pc, the same project and settings.xml working

Comment: @ZNK-M not using proxy internet.

Comment: Thanks to all.It causes about routers firewall.I resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

It might have to do with proxy settings? Check if you've mentioned the proxy tag in settings.xml or you may want to pass the environment parameters specifying the proxy and port number when doing mvn clean install.

Something like this

mvn clean install -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy_name -Dhttp.proxyPort=port_number